# Как передать $pdo в функцию модели

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, pdo

У меня есть папка ***config*** в которой лежит файл ***db.php***, в котором содержится следующий код:

```
<?php

$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'test';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpassword = '';

$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);

$dsn = "mysql:host = $host; dbname = $dbname; charset = $charset";

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $opt);
```

Потом у меня есть папка с моделями: ***models*** в котором лежит файл ***WorkersModel.php*** со следующим кодом:

```
<?php

function getAllWorkers() {
    $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM `workers`');

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $row['name'];
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что я не могу получить доступ к переменной ***$pdo*** из этой функции, вернее могу, но только если внутри функции объявлю ***$pdo*** глобальной:

```
<?php

function getAllWorkers() {
    global $pdo;
    ...
```

Эту модель подключает контроллер из папки ***controllers*** и вызывает функции модели в своих функциях.

Все эти папки:
***models***,
***config***,
***controllers*** находятся на одном уровне. На этом же уровне находится папка ***www***, в которой в свою очередь лежит ***index.php***, который "вызывает" контроллеры, подключает файлы из папки ***config*** и содержит такой код:

```
<?php

require_once '../config/config.php';
require_once '../libs/Functions.php';
require_once '../config/db.php';

$controllerName = isset($_GET['controller']) ? ucfirst($_GET['controller']) : 'Index';
$actionName = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : 'index';

loadPage($twig, $controllerName, $actionName);
```

В файле ***Functions.php*** у меня содержатся всякие общие функции, типа загрузки страницы и загрузки шаблона.

Так вот: как мне *правильно* инициализировать PDO и подключить его к модели?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения Вашей задачи, думаю, неплохо подойдет паттерн [Singleton](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)). С помощью этого паттерна можно создать объект, который будет доступен во всем приложении. Говорят, правда, что сейчас синглтон записали в антипаттерны, но в Вашем случае его использование должно быть неплохим решением.

1. В файле **db.php** вы размещаете класс для подключения к БД:

   ```
   <?php class DB {

       private static $instance;  // экземпляр объекта

       /**
        * 
        * @var PDO 
        */
       private $pdo = false;

       /* Защищаем от создания через new DB */

       private function __construct() {

       }

       /* Защищаем от создания через клонирование */

       private function __clone() {

       }

       /* Защищаем от создания через unserialize */

       private function __wakeup() {

       }

       /**
        * Возвращает единственный экземпляр класса
        * @return DB
        */
       public static function getInstance() {
           if (empty(self::$instance)) {
               self::$instance = new self();
           }
           return self::$instance;
       }

       /**
        * Подключаемся к БД
        * @param type $dsn
        * @param type $dbuser
        * @param type $dbpassword
        * @param type $opt
        * @throws Exception
        */
       public function connect($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $opt) {
           try {
               $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $opt);
           } catch (Exception $e) {
               throw $e;
           }
       }

       /**
        * Получить ссылку на PDO
        * @return boolean
        */
       public function get_pdo() {
           if ($this->pdo instanceof PDO) {
               return $this->pdo;
           }
           return false;
       }

       /**
        * Закрываем соединение с БД
        */
       public function close() {
           $this->pdo = null;
       }

   }

   /**
    * Параметры для подключения к БД
    */
   $host = 'localhost';
   $dbname = 'test';
   $charset = 'utf8';

   $dbuser = 'root';
   $dbpassword = '';

   $opt = array(
       PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
       PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
   );

   $dsn = "mysql:host = {$host}; dbname = {$dbname}; charset = {$charset}";

   /**
    * *******************************
    */

   /**
    * Попытка подключени к БД
    */
   try {
       DB::getInstance()->connect($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $opt);
   } catch (Exception $e) {
       echo $e->getMessage();
       exit;
   }
   /**
    * *******************************
    */
   ```
2. В файле **index.php** после вызова *load_page* :

   ```
   DB::getInstance()->close();
   ```
3. И теперь вы можете получить доступ к PDO во всех файлах модели, например вот так:

**WorkersModel.php**

```
<?php

function getAllWorkers() {
    $pdo = DB::getInstance()->get_pdo();
    $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM `workers`');

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $row['name'];
    }
}
```

Возможно я ошибаюсь, но, по приведенным примерам кода, мне кажется что Вы не очень хорошо знакомы с парадигмой ООП. Если это действительно так, то настоятельно рекомендую Вам основательно взяться за изучение этой парадигмы.

Comment: Вы правы. Изучать ООП я начал только недавно, спасибо за ответ и за наглядный пример.

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку речь здесь идет не о классах, а о функциях, я думаю, здесь надо просто забыть все красивые слова про *модели* и *контроллеры*, честно назвать свой подход процедурным винегретом, и не париться по поводу использования global - для такого подхода это идеальное решение.

Comment: Спасибо. Хотя я всё же лучше начну использовать ООП... Или пытаться :)